# What anime is this white angel costume from?

Tags: merchandise

My friend found this costume, which she's seen before but can't find where it's from.

[image: Costume]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an outfit worn by Panty from [Panty & Stocking with Garterbelt](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=7529)

[image]